# Get error 500 when I try auto-login using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, module, internal-server-error, autologin

I'm trying to create a login bot using selenium and when it logs in it returns a server error, I don't know if it's an internal error or it's because I'm using a bot.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

from getpass  import getpass

email= input("Enter your username")
password= getpass("Enter your password: ")

driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\alvar\\env\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.basic-fit.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-BFE-Site/es_ES/Login-Start")

username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
username_textbox.send_keys(email)

password_textbox= driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password_textbox.send_keys(password)


login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/section[1]/div[2]/form/div[4]/button").submit()
```

[Here's the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naGWx.png)

Comment: Error 500 typically represents something wrong with the server processing the request. Are you able to do the same login process manually without getting the error?

Comment: maybe server has some problem only today, Try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `click()` button, not `submit()`

---

When you `click` then it runs JavaScript which checks login/password.

When you `submit` then it doesn't click button but it sends `form` to assigned url `<form action="https://www.basic-fit.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-BFE-Site/es_ES/Login-Submit"...>` and it makes problem.